# weakly non linear analysis of Swift-Hohenberg equation:

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Do you have any text book or reference that I can look into for the weakly non linear analysis for solving following swift-hohenberg equation? 
Also if you could help me solve it, that would be great :)

$$∂_t u=r u−(∂_{xx}+1)^2 u+ γu^2−u^3$$